# OS X: Agent/Daemon shows up in launchctl list, but cannot find its .plist

Tags: osx-el-capitan, daemon, launchctl

I've been having this issue for quite some time now. It doesn't really hurt my workflow, but every time I want to look for something in the console, it gets in the way, since there's the following message every 10 seconds:

```
(timestamp) xpcproxy[1247]: CFPreferences could not connect to its daemon.
          Preferences using the connection 0x0 will be volatile and will not be persisted to disk.
(timestamp) com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.hp.productresearch[1247]) LaunchServices returned a bundle URL that does not match with the LoginItem's known association.
(timestamp) com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.hp.productresearch) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

If I use

```
launchctl remove com.hp.productresearch
```

it goes away, but comes back after a system restart.

I have not installed any full-fledged HP driver that I remember of, and searching HP's forums did not yield any useful result.

How can I find out what is going on? Where's the entry that forces this agent/daemon to keep respawning every time the OS restarts?
Is there a way to manually COMPLETELY remove this LaunchServices entry?

I have also tried LaunchControl; I can't seem to find any records of the agent/daemon using this application for some reason.

Comment: looks like this agent/daemon was installed by an automatic software update run as seen here:
`Oct 25 17:09:49 thanars-iMac system_installd[14235]: PackageKit: Bundle com.hp.productresearch is nested inside upgrade-bundle or atomic-update-bundle and will not be version-checked`

Comment: there's also this text in a "HP Product Research.log" file: `2017-10-25 14:12:47 +0000: Removed launchd job plist at /Users/thanar/Library/LaunchAgents/com.hp.productresearch.plist: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "“com.hp.productresearch.plist” couldn’t be removed." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/thanar/Library/LaunchAgents/com.hp.productresearch.plist, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Remove
), NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdba04314d0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
`

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the hp drivers by removing the "hp" folder from /Libary/Printers/. OS X re-downloaded the drivers a few minutes later and automatically installed. It now seems that the issue is resolved. However, I now see the following lines after each restart:

> (timestamp) com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100008.Aqua) Could not import service from caller: caller = otherbsd.417, service = com.hp.productresearch, error = 119: Service is disabled
>
> (timestamp) otherbsd[417]: Could not submit LoginItem job com.hp.productresearch: 119: Service is disabled

Part of the question still stands, though: Where's the entry that forces an agent/daemon to keep respawning every time the OS restarts? Is there a way to manually COMPLETELY remove a LaunchServices entry?